# How to add more key/value pairs to JSON formData after it has been declared

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have this ajax formData:

```
data.formData = {action : 'process_uploads',filetitle : newtitle, filehash : file_hash, aspect : aspect, uploadlanguage : uploadlanguage, thefilesize : data.files[0].size};
```

I need to append more keys/values after this has already been declared AND submitted so I can submit it again.  How can I do that?

i.e.

```
//declare original data
data.formData = {action : 'process_uploads',filetitle : newtitle, filehash : file_hash, aspect : aspect, uploadlanguage : uploadlanguage, thefilesize : data.files[0].size};

//submit form and gather result on success
var jqXHR = data.submit().success(function(result, textStatus, jqXHR){

  var json = JSON.parse(result);



  if(json.files[0].hash != file_hash ){

//NEED TO ADD MORE VARIABLES AND SUBMIT AGAIN

data.formData.retryfile = '1';
data.formData.hash = 'file_hash';
//this isn't working.


     data.submit();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
let jsonData =  {action : 'process_uploads',filetitle : newtitle, filehash : file_hash, aspect : aspect, uploadlanguage : uploadlanguage, thefilesize : data.files[0].size};
jsonData.newfield =1;

console.log(jsonData);
data.formData = jsonData;
```

OR using [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
let infoA = {action : 'process_uploads'};
let infoB = {newfield:'1'};


let jsonData = Object.assign(infoA, infoB);
console.log(jsonData);
data.formData = jsonData;
```

In your updated code:

```
//declare original data
var jsonData = {action : 'process_uploads',filetitle : newtitle, filehash : file_hash, aspect : aspect, uploadlanguage : uploadlanguage, thefilesize : data.files[0].size};
data.formData = jsonData;

//submit form and gather result on success
var jqXHR = data.submit().success(function(result, textStatus, jqXHR){

  var json = JSON.parse(result);


  var status = json['status'];


  if(json.files[0].hash != file_hash ){

   //NEED TO ADD MORE VARIABLES AND SUBMIT AGAIN

   jsonData.retryfile = '1';
   jsonData.hash = 'file_hash';

   data.formData = jsonData;

   data.submit();

}
```

Comment: Here you are appending it before data.formData has been declared.  I need to add it after it has been declared already and previously submitted.

Comment: You can define jsonData at any moment, and set to "data.formData" whenever you want.

Comment: Can you swap infoB with data.formData?

Comment: yes, you could swap or add more obj... Object.assign{{}, infoA , data.formData , {another:'x'} } ;

Comment: I updated it to make it more clear what I am trying to do.

Comment: I tried data.formData.hash = 'file_hash' but it didn't work.