# How to push ajax serializeObject function

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am going to `serializeObject` and pass the object parameters received from the form.

I pushed to add id parameter but js error. (`data.push is not function`)

I'm asking to `querystring` or push to an array element.

```
var data = $('form#buildForm').serializeObject() + "&param=testplanId";  // not working

var data = $('form#buildForm').serialize() + "&param=testplanId"; // not working
```

===========this is my sample code==========

```js
$("#addBuild").on("click", function(){

   var testplanId = [[${testplan_id}]];   // Parameter to send.
   if(confirm("")){
        var data = $('form#buildForm').serializeObject();
        data.push({name:'testplanId', value:'testplanId'});     

       // ajax 처리
 $.ajax({
              type : "post",
       url : "createBuild.json",
              data : JSON.stringify(data),
             dataType : "JSON",
      contentType : "application/json",
       success : function(data){
       },

        }):


   }

});
```

Comment: Try this data.testplanId = 'something'

Comment: serializeObject ? from which library?   check similiar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58143630/how-to-add-more-key-value-pairs-to-json-formdata-after-it-has-been-declared/58143744#58143744

Comment: amazing @Casper ! So simple! Thank you~!